# python name mangling using json dumps

Tags: python, json

(Been using python a while but my lingo is weak so bear with me)

I have a bunch of objects I'm adding to each other in python. I'm serializing the objects using their `__dict__` attribute (with `__init__` function `self.__field` sort of thing.) I'm printing out the objects using `json.dumps` for a proof of concept for an API port I'm doing. The problem is I'm using name mangling along with python properties so that when I print it looks sort of as follows

```
{
"_Type1__field": {
    "A": {
        "_Type1-1__field": [
            {
                "_Type1-1-1__field": [
                    {
                        "_Type1-1-1-1__field": null,
                        "field": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "_Type1-1-1-1__field": null,
                        "field": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_Type1-1-2__field": [
                    {
                        "_Type1-1-2-1__field1": null,
                        "_Type1-1-2-1__field2": null,
                        "_Type1-1-2-1__field3": null,
                        "field1": {
                            "field": 3853579331
                        },
                        "field2": 1373546537126.0,
                        "field3": 1373632937126.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it the mangled getting picked up along with the property objects?
The typical object like the Typex-x-x (Typex and Typex-x are outer objects) is set up like so

```
class Type(inheritance):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__field= None
        self.__field2= {}

    @property
    def field(self):
        return self.__field

    @deviceId.setter
    def field(self, value):
        self.__field = value

    @property
    def field2(self):
        return self.__field2

    @field2.setter
    def field2(self, value):
        self.__field2 = value
```

It's not really a problem, I'd just like to know what's going on and why each field is showing up as `None` and with its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and moreover you are reinventing the wheel.

Use `pickle` http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html or better `cPickle` http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle to serialize Python objects.

The `Python` philosophy is `batteries included` so use `stdlib` whenever possible.

Comment: Well, the attempted solution was my problem. json.dumps was doing weird stuff. Moreover json is a module. I thank you for your recommendation of a different module that will hopefully work better.